# Trying to simplify the following boolean expression but suck and new to this

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

**Expression:**

$[x + (yz)](x' + z)$

**My attempt:**

1. $[x + (yz)](x' + z)$
2. $(x + y)(x + z)(x' + z) \quad \textit{Distributive law}$

The answer is supposed to be: $(x + y) \times z$

N.B. I am still new to this and learning, I am using the following book:

```
Discrete Mathematics for Computing / Edition 3
by Peter Grossman
```

Comment: Hint. Probably $(x+z)(x’+z)$ have to be equal to $z$. Which is easy to see to be true.

Comment: @Aig, how? I am a bit confused by the x  and x' there. Because, otherwise, I think $x(z + z)$ would've been possible.

Comment: @Aig, which axiom are you using in this context?

Comment: Before any axioms, I recommend that you understand on the intuitive level, why it is obvious. Those operations are just *and*, *or* and *not*, which we all use in everyday-life logic, after all.

Comment: @AlixBlaine If [(it's raining OR you go shopping) AND (it isn't raining OR you go shopping)], then you go shopping.

Comment: [x+(yz)](x′+z)=x(x′+z)+(yz)(x′+z)=xz+x'yz+yz=xz+(x'+1)yz=xz+yz=(x+y)z. Manipulate them using algebraic laws...

Comment: @Aig, explain how you get from $(x+z)(x'+z)$ to **z** here, I am confused. Unless x and x' cancel each other out.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, your expression is hard to follow along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $ [x+(yz)](x′+z) $ `distributiv law =>`
- $ (x+y)(x+z)(x′+z) $  `commutative law =>`
- $ (x+y)(z+x)(z+x') $   `distributive law =>`
- $ (x+y)(z+(xx')) $   `complement Law =>`
- $ (x+y)(z+0) $    `identity law =>`
- $ (x+y)z $

(Laws From: [Laws of Boolean Algebra (electronics-tutorials.ws)](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html))

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think $z+0=z$ is the **first identity law**. Saw now, sorry. I got confused by the **complement law** a line before.

Comment: you are right its confusing. i will reformat the post so that the law is in the line before its applicaiton and not after...that way it should be more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mond. ;-)